# Check if member exists in role

Tags: powershell, ssas

I want to check if both role then member exist already, but i am getting error that `FindByName` is not a method of `Member`

```
$db = $Analysis_Server.Databases.FindByName($cube)
$ROLE = $db.Roles.FindByName($cube_ROLE)
$memberexists = $ROLE.Members.FindByName($member)
if ($ROLE) # if role exists already...check if group exists, or just add group
{
   if ($memberexists)
    {
        write "member exists!"
    }
   else
    {
        $ROLE.Members.Add($member)
        $ROLE.Update()
    }
}
```

Comment: Whats the type of $Analysis_Server or the command used to populate that variable?

Comment: @ArcSet $Analysis_Server = New-Object Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Server ........and for the role: [Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Role] there is also [Microsoft.AnalysisServices.RoleMembers] but not sure of the difference really

Comment: `Roles.Members.FindByName($member)` doesnt make any sense. You didnt define a varible those properties arnt attached to a object. Maybe you meant `$Role.Members`

Comment: @ArcSet yes my bad i fixed the script here: $memberexists = $ROLE.Members.FindByName($member)

Comment: OK So `$ROLE.Members` is a **RoleMemberCollection Object**. I dont see a Method FindByName() method. Now I seems you will need to Iterate through the collection or use the method Contains(RoleMember Object) Method

Comment: @ArcSet yes i also looked on MSDocs and I didnt find anything...I want to still be able to check if member exists, but idk any other way...

Comment: is the $member a string ? Is it the Name or SID?

Comment: @ArcSet yes, it holds an actual member name

Comment: try `$memberexists = $False;
$memberexists = $ROLE.Members | ?{ $_.Name -like $Member } | %{ $True } `

Comment: @ArcSet i didnt get any output

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187540/discussion-between-arcset-and-cataster).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So `$Role.Members` is a **RoleMemberCollection Object**. We can **Enumerate** over it since it doesnt have the method **FindByName()**. This will get a **RoleMember Object** with the property Name. So what the code will look like is...

```
$memberexists = $False
$memberexists = $ROLE.Members.GetEnumerator() | ?{$_.name -like $Member} | select -First 1 | %{$True}
enter code here
```

Comment: appreciate the help!